# change classname of element based on route in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've been searching around the documents and various forums for a little while and I cannot seem to find any **React Router** component or workaround which can achieve something like this.

Similar to how we have the `NavLink` component, is there any component within the **React Router** specification which we can use to a similar degree in order to change `classNames` on a `div` element when the route matches?

For example:

```
<Element 
    exact to={["/one", "/two"]} 
    className="default-class" 
    activeClassName="open"
>
    <ChildComponent />
</Element>
```

Which defines that, when a user is on at `/two` or `/two`, it would render:

```
<div class="default-class open">
     <!-- child components !-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to define the className based on route. You can do it inside component using `useLocation` hook provided by react-router

```
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-rom'

const location = useLocation();


if(location =='/one'){
 return SOMETHING
}
else{
    return SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js) for the `NavLink` component.  My first thought is to copy and paste that code and turn it into a `withActiveStyling` HOC.  Unfortunately it uses some internals which are not exported from the 'react-router-dom' package so it's not just copy and paste.  But we can use that source as a template.

This HOC accepts all of the props of a `NavLink`, with some changes to `to`: it only accepts a `string` or `array` or strings but not a function.

It edits the props `className` and `style` of the `Wrapped Component` to include the `activeClassName` and/or `activeStyle` if the current location matches the `to` location.  Props `exact`, `strict`, and `sensitive` will be used to determine whether it's a match or not.

```
const withActiveStyling = ( WrappedComponent ) => {
  return (props) => {
    const {
      activeClassName = "active",
      activeStyle,
      className: classNameProp,
      isActive: isActiveProp,
      location: locationProp,
      style: styleProp
    } = props;
    const location = useLocation();
    const currentLocation = locationProp || location;
    // get a match object (or null) based on the whether the current location matches the props (to, exact, etc)
    const match = matchPath(currentLocation.pathname, {
      ...props,
      path: props.to
    });

    const isActive = !!(isActiveProp
      ? isActiveProp(match, currentLocation)
      : match);

    const className = isActive
      ? joinClassnames(classNameProp, activeClassName)
      : classNameProp;
    const style = isActive ? { ...styleProp, ...activeStyle } : styleProp;

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} style={style} className={className} />;
  };
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/withactivestyling-khu6f?file=/src/App.tsx) with typescript annotations